# custom rewrite rules will not be added to wordpress rewrite_rules database

Tags: rewrite-rules

I want to make rewrite.

this is my rewrite code:

```
function coinDedicatePage_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_tag('%coinName%', '([^&]+)');

    add_rewrite_rule('^coin/(.+?)/?$', 'index.php?page_id=44008&coinName=$matches[1]','top');

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);

}

add_action('init', 'coinDedicatePage_rewrite',10,0);
```

I don't want to write anything to `htaccess` and don't want to change it.

but finally it does not direct me to the page that I declared in `add_rewrite_rule`

after this code when I get rewrites array with this code: `$rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );`
I see the rewrite rule what I want there was not in `$rules` array.

finally how add and inject my desired rules to wordpress system?!

Comment: Remove the `global $wp_rewrite;` and `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);` and flush the rewrite rules by visiting the permalink settings page.

Comment: @SallyCJ permalink settings page changes htaccess content and I don't want to wordpress changes htaccess content